# flask-migrate doesn't detect models

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

I am reading (and watching) about Flask-Migrate here:
https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/
and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJibNSI-iaE#t=21

and doing everything from this tutorial:

- I started a local postgres server (using Postgres.App, which started the server at postgresql://localhost:5432)
- updated configs as per said tutorial
- updated app.py, created a models.py etc.

After you install Flask-Migrate and run

```
python manage.py db init
python manage.py db migrate
```

it should detect all tables declared in models.py.

In my case, it detects nothing. And, based on the comments to the tutorial, it's not just my case.
So, how do I make this work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure your model is imported by your app. In most cases your `views.py` should do that. But you can also import it directly from your `app.py`.

Comment: Hi, do you have an example for this? I am still encountering the issue.

Comment: Hello sir @RyanAquino the file migrations/env.py have the line "from myapp import models" commented, just replace that with your data and that is it.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that you're importing your models the same way throughout your application.

For example, I was using the following in my `__init__.py`:

```
from .models import *
```

And the following in my `manage.py`:

```
from databases import models
```

Because these have diff namespaces, flask_manager thinks there are duplicated tables. *(Note, I found this solution in the following [github issue / thread](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/672#issuecomment-632340238).)*

Fix and all will be well.

Answer (score 2):

If Flask can't detect your models, add this to env.py in migrations folder:
`from models import *`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your model literally anywhere in your code, so SQLAlchemy can recognize it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).